# Pagination for multiple query set from different models

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get data from multiple models from multiple serializers. and I got the response and data but what is happen it didn't gives me the "count", "next" , and "previous" keys to use it for pagination.

and I created a view as following:

views.py

```
class PlayerNotificationView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        activity_invitation_to_join = ActivityInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user,
                                                                active=True, status__in=('P', 'k',))
    team_invitation_to_join = TeamInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user, active=True,
                                                        status__in=('P', 'k',))
    team_player_left_team = TeamInvite.objects.filter(team__admin=self.request.user, active=True, status="L")
    activity_unread = ActivityInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user, read="False").count()
    team_unread = TeamInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user, read="False").count()
    total = activity_unread + team_unread
    un_read = [{'activity_unread': activity_unread,
                'team_unread': team_unread,
                'total': total}]

    context = [{

        "request": request,
    }]

    activity_serializer = MyActivityInviteSerializer(activity_invitation_to_join, many=True, context=context)
    team_serializer = MyTeamInviteSerializer(team_invitation_to_join, many=True, context=context)
    team_player_left_serializer = MyTeamInviteSerializer(team_player_left_team, many=True, context=context)

    un_sorted_queryset = activity_serializer.data + team_serializer.data + team_player_left_serializer.data

    from operator import itemgetter
    response = sorted(un_sorted_queryset, key=itemgetter('updated_date'), reverse=True) + un_read

    context = {
        "notifications": response,
    }
    return Response(context)
```

and it return response like this:

```
{
    "notifications": [
        {
.
. 
.
}]}
```

and what i need exactly is paginate the result to be like this:

```
{
    "count": 2,

"next": next,

"previous": previous,

"notifications": [
    {.. }]}

}
```

So, how can I do this ?
Please any one can help me?

and if there any solution for this point in a different way to get data from multiple models and multiple serializers.

hope this is readable and clear to understand. 
many thanks,

**update**
**Solution**
this update and solution to help any one faced same issue and he didn't get the answer
I did it like what "schillingt" said in answers as following:

```
class LimitPagination(MultipleModelLimitOffsetPagination):
    default_limit = 1

class PlayerNotificationView(FlatMultipleModelAPIView):
pagination_class = LimitPagination
add_model_type = True
sorting_fields = ['updated_date']

def get_querylist(self):

    activity_invitation_to_join = ActivityInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user,
                                                                active=True, status__in=('P', 'k',))
    team_invitation_to_join = TeamInvite.objects.filter(to_user=self.request.user, active=True,
                                                        status__in=('P', 'k',))
    team_player_left_team = TeamInvite.objects.filter(team__admin=self.request.user, active=True, status="L")

    # un_sorted_queryset = activity_serializer.data + team_serializer.data + team_player_left_serializer.data

    querylist = (
        {'queryset': activity_invitation_to_join.distinct(), 'serializer_class': MyActivityInviteSerializer},
        {'queryset': team_invitation_to_join.distinct(), 'serializer_class': MyTeamInviteSerializer},
        {'queryset': team_player_left_team.distinct(), 'serializer_class': MyTeamInviteSerializer},
    )

    return querylist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate a Pagination class and use that to generate the content. However, I would recommend using [`django-rest-multiple-models`](https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels) as it's a bit cleaner than what you would have to do. You'll need to override the method that filters down the queryset to limit it to the current user, but that should be relatively easy.

If you do decide to do it on your own, here is [DRF's documentation on pagination.](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/pagination#paginating-querysets)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I did it for models without sorting results from all models together and it works fine , but I need to re-sort the results from all models based on created_date so maybe first dict from first table and the second one from second table and the third result from first table, 

I cant get any thing in django rest multiple models talks about this.

can you guide me to do this?

many thanks

Comment: many thanks again ,, 
I did it using reset multiple models with pagination and sorting...

many tanks

Comment: If you are looking into using cursor pagination which is more performant for querying larger tables, this library won't be a compatible solution.

Comment: Hey @Amirsalar, I am trying to implement cursor pagination on the nested objects of a Serializer on a ModelViewSet. 

Essentially, a 1-to-many relationship between Post and Comments. When i query for posts, i would like to return paginated comments of a post in the serializer. i understand that regular pagination with limit and offset is a lot easier but i have a UI flow that i think only cursor pagination will be able to achieve.